# Dojo. Different colors in Device than in preview

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using WL 5.0.6

I create a new hybrid application with dojo.

I create a EdgeToEdgeList with two ListItem.

When I preview it, list items and background are grey but when I run the application in the Android device the list items and background are black.

How can I change this behaviour?

Thank you.

Comment: The theme used by the preview is probably an iOS theme, while Android has its own theme.

Comment: How can change the theme used by Android? I'm doing the preview over the Android App so it shouldn't be an iOs theme.

Comment: Something is strange with the mobile browser simulator.   I'm running it in FireFox with User Agent Switching enabled ... and you're right, it is showing me the iOS theme in an android preview.  It might have to do with browser version  ... I'm not sure.  In the Rich Page Editor, if you set the device to an android device, and the skin to android, does it show you the dark Android theme?

Comment: I didn't know about that in the rich page.... Any case in the rich page editor it appears in black once I change it, by default it load the grey one, I change it to other Android Device and it change the color to black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the theme that you see in the preview on Android, remove:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script>
```

from your main html.  You are probably then going to want to add something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dojox/mobile/themes/iphone/iphone.css">
```

Comment: The only reference that appears to deviceTheme.js is in the file build-dojo.xml, I have commented it and added your css line to the main html file without success, in the device it appears in black and in the preview it fails, nothing is displayed.

Comment: oops.  I missed that you are on 5.0.6.  In that case, remove "dojox/mobile/deviceTheme" from the require in your main JavaScript file

Comment: May be I'm missing something.

Comment: May be I'm missing something. deviceTheme.js is only in the build-dojo.xml. It is not in any other file like html or js files.
If I remove the deveiceTheme.js line from the build-dojo.xml the nothing related to dojo is rendered.

Comment: in 5.0.6, by default it is required in the main JavaScript file for the app.  ("dojox/mobile/deviceTheme"  (no ".js" use in require()))  In 6.0 is is included in the main HTML file and so it is deviceTheme.js

Comment: That works, thank you. I have removed the dojox/mobile/deviceTheme from the require in the default application javascript file and added the <link rel="stylesheet" href="dojox/mobile/themes/iphone/iphone.css"> to the the main html page.
The good point is that you can edit the file deviceTheme.js for debugging and knowing which css file is loading.